# Heroku error on PGconn.open(:dbname => 'EBDX') Works fine on local, but not after deploying on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, connection

I am getting this error while connecting to the database 
 `PG::ConnectionBad (could not connect to server: No such file or directory
2014-05-17T08:04:30.292246+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-05-17T08:04:30.297461+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-05-17T08:04:30.297469+00:00 app[web.1]:    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?`

My code works on local and connects to the database normally, but doesn't work after deploying on Heroku. Following is the error line from my rails controller.
`conn = PGconn.open(:dbname => 'EBDX')`

I checked my Heroku database using 
`Heroku pg:psql`
I can see my tables there, but still get the error

Answer (score 1):

When you were working locally, you connected through a Unix socket, which is enabled by default. After deploying on Heroku you have to connect over TCP/IP. It looks like you have to update the connection parameters in your code to point to the Heroku server.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. That makes sense. Do you know what i should set the parameters as.

Comment: @user3639521 No, I cannot give you those parameters because they are specific to your deployment. You should inquire with the technical support for whomever is hosting Heroku.